# How to set up relations

Tags: sql, sqlite, lua

I'm new to databases. Using SQLite3 to store Objects of a Lua script, I want to interlace 2 tables.

Let's say the lua objects look like this:

```
class_A.name           = ""
class_A.currency       = 0
class_A.salary         = 0
class_A.misc           = {}
class_A.customers      = {}  -- this stores related objects of class_B
class_A:function1() something is something end
class_A:function2() something is something else end

class_B.name           = ""
class_B.id             = ""
class_B.value          = 0
class_B.consultant     = {} -- this stores related objects of class_B
class_B:function1() something is different end
```

Now I'm storing these in SQLite tables. The "relatedObjects"-var should be stored in a 3. table, this should look similar to this:

```
-- class_A table:
| Idx  | Name  | currency | salary | misc |
|------|-------|----------|--------|------|
|  1   | john  | 1,233.00 | 2,300  | null |
|  2   | eva   | 4,100.00 | 1,970  | null |

-- class_B table
| Idx  | Name     | currency | salary | misc |
|------|----------|----------|--------|------|
|  1   | peterson | 1,233.00 | 2,300  | null |
|  2   | griffin  | 4,100.00 | 1,970  | null | 
|  3   | simpson  | 2,738.00 | 2,100  | null |

--Interleave
--index of the respective table
| consultant | csutomer |
|------------|----------|
|      1     |    2     |
|      2     |    1     |
|      3     |    1     |
|      3     |    2     |
```

I hope you got my point, don't think this is verry difficult and thus I feel pretty dump right now.
The Idx value is AUTOINCREMENT, so ther should not occur any confusion.

The question is HOW TO set up this Interleave table.

I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE Interleave( _A INTEGER FOREIGN KEY Class_A.Idx, _B INTEGER FOREIGN KREY Class_B.Idx)

INSERT INTO Interleave (_A, _B) VALUES ( Class_A.Idx WHERE name = 'john', Class_B.Idx WHERE name = 'griffin')
```

But it tells me "near "WHERE": syntax error:" (No errorcode)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Everything you've written looks OK.

Comment: This is just the concept of how it should look like, but I've no idea how to. Really new to databases.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this hepls (I will be assuming that you are really new to db):

1. First, name the columns with readable names, you will thank your self later for that
2. Second, change the insert clause to:

   ```
   INSERT INTO Interleave (_A, _B) VALUES ( (SELECT Idx FROM Class_A WHERE name = 'john'), (SELECT Idx FROM Class_B WHERE name = 'griffin'))
   ```